# Consecutive messages of various size over a network

Tags: network-programming, messaging, network-protocols

I want to send *consecutive* messages of *various size* over a network. Each message is serialized by the sender to a byte array and sent over TCP. I will use some (C# influenced) pseudocode.

```
CustomClass message = new CustomClass(data: 12345);
byte[] messageBytes = Serialize(message);
socket.Send(messageBytes);
```

On the receiving end I need to be able to distinguish each message so that I can deserialize it.

```
byte[] messageBytes = new byte[...];
socket.Receive(messageBytes);
CustomClass message = Deserialize(messageBytes);
```

So far I've come up with two different approaches:

## Length prefix

I send the length of the byte array and then the byte array itself. This way on the receiving end I need to read the length and then read that many bytes. This should work fine but has a performance penalty with messages that are overly large. In that case I would have to allocate a byte array (or byte arrays) for the whole message so that I can calculate its length.

## Separator

I send the byte array followed by a separator. That works well for messages of any size. Problem is - what if the separator is present in the message bytes?

## Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to improve length prefixing so it works well for large messages, too?
2. Is there a dedicated separator symbol or string for situations like these? Is there an alternative to escaping in order to make it work?
3. Is there any other approach apart from those 2?

Comment: Why would it be a performance penalty for large messages when you're having a header with the length? I would say that using a separator is more of a performance penalty as you then have to check every byte or word received. In the first case, you read a single fixed-length header (with the length) and then know exactly how many bytes to receive, no matter the length of the data.

Comment: Also in the second case (with separator) you also have to be able to handle partial messages. Like if you receive a packet containing the end of one message and the beginning of the next. This case is side-stepped when you have the exact length to receive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I consider length-prefixing a performance penalty for large messages because the sender has to allocate **the whole** message in a byte array in memory before sending it. At least I can't think of a way to use a fixed-length buffer with length prefixing. I **entirely** agree about the drawbacks of separators you mentioned.

Comment: You don't *have* to keep a separate buffer for the header and the data. Just send the length as a separate "message" followed by the data. On the receiving end you must use two (or more!) receives anyway to be able to read the header and the data. The separator case have one "pro" point though: You could receive the whole message *including* the separator in a single receive, but you still have to send it as two (unless you want to allocate a buffer and append the separator into it).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I don't think I've mentioned anything about separate buffers in my previous comment. What I mean is that you have to **know** the length of the message in order to send it **before** the actual message bytes. And you learn it after serializing the message itself which requires a large buffer, which I state is a problem. I won't use a separate buffer just for the message size (int16 or int32) for sure. Also, as you know, there is a difference between calling *Send* and actually sending the data over the wire. Which I think depends on the Naggle algorithm and calling Flush.

Comment: As far as I can see the only difference between the two methods is the protocol to separate messages (length versus separator). You still need to do the serialization for the separator alternative, so the creation of the byte-array still needs to be done.

Comment: I think serialization and deserialization can use a fixed buffer length if the APIs allow working with something like streams, which could save allocation for large messages.

Comment: For completion´s sake, there are more than two ways to do what OP wants: FTP for example uses two connections: one to control the data flow, one to do the actual transfer of the data (has, of course its own can of worms). Alternatively, one can create rudimentary protocol, something like each logical "message" is preceded by one byte indicating if there are more messages expected, and n bytes to indicate the length of the current message. This would allow breaking up a continuous stream without knowing its total length beforehand. And of course one can create a full fledged fancy protocol...